# Android getting the clicked value from an alert box

Tags: android

I have an alert box with a list of channels.

I would like to get the value of the clicked channel.

Is this possible?

I have this so far..

```
  public void ShowChannelDialog(){

      String[] channels = new String[_publicChannels.size()];
      channels = _publicChannels.toArray(channels);

      AlertDialog.Builder showChannel = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
      showChannel.setTitle("Channel List ("+(_publicChannels.size()-1)+" channels)");


      showChannel.setItems(channels, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
            _publicChannels.clear();
            if (item == (_publicChannels.size())) {
                System.out.println("NEW CHANNEL");
                CreateNewChannel();
                dialog.dismiss();
            }else{
                String channel = String.valueOf(item);
                System.out.println("Selected: " + channel);
            }
        }
    });
```

String.valueof(item) only gives me the int value in the array, I want the actual text value.

Thank you!

Comment: you can have a look on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10068848/android-keeping-track-of-checked-values-in-multi-select-dialog/10068877#10068877

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try following

```
 if (item == (_publicChannels.size())) {
            System.out.println("NEW CHANNEL");
            CreateNewChannel();
            dialog.dismiss();
        }else{
            String channel = channels[item];
            System.out.println("Selected: " + channel);
        }
```

Comment: I have tried this, but it I cant make channel `final` as the line `channels = _publicChannels.toArray(channels);` doesn't allow it!

Answer (score 1):

instead of `String.valueOf(item)`, use `channels[item]`. You'll need to make channels `final` as well.

Answer (score 0):

Sample CONFIRMATION dialog box on exit

```
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit?")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("Yes",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int id) {
                                finish();
                            }
                        })
                .setNegativeButton("No",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int id) {
                                dialog.cancel();
                            }
                        });
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
```